# Why can we calculate the molar mass of a non volatile solute using lowering in vapour pressure?

Tags: solutions

Apparently it is possible to calculate the molecular mass of a non volatile solute using relative lowering of vapour pressure using the equation:

[image]

Where P is the total vapour pressure of the solution, Po is the vapour pressure of pure solvent, W2 is the weight of the solute and M2 is it's molar mass.

My textbook derives this equation only using Raoult's law assuming we have a dilute solution.

But I wonder, relative lowering in vapour press is a colligative property so it should be independent of the identity of the solute yet we can calculate the identity of the solute (molar mass) using it. Maybe colligative properties are independent of the number of solute particles but they are dependent on the mass of the solute particles somehow? Is this correct?

Comment: Colligative properties depend on the ratio n(solute)/n(solvent), regardless of the solute. But n=m/M, so for given m(solute), n(solute) obviously depends on M(solute).